# How to get image in collectionview cell from json using objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uiimageview

```
self->SCImageArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            self->SCLabelArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSDictionary *SCDic = [maindic objectForKey:@"specialcategories"];
            for (NSDictionary *SCDictionary in SCDic){
                NSString *strimage = [SCDictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
                [self->SCImageArr addObject:strimage];
                NSLog(@"SCImage :%@", strimage);  
                NSString *strname = [SCDictionary objectForKey:@"text"];
                [self->SCLabelArr addObject:strname];
                NSLog(@"SClabelname :%@", strname);
            } 
            [self.specialCategoriesCollectionView reloadData];
```

my cell code here

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIndentifer = @"Cell";
    SpecialCategoriesCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIndentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.categoriesImages.image = [UIImage imageWithData:SCImageArr];
    cell.categoriesNameLabel.text = self.specialCategoriesLabel[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

How to get image in collectionview cell from json using objective c?

Comment: Please name your variables starting with a lowercase. Don't use multiple arrays for values that are synce'd. Instead parse the dictionary into a custom class. Also what is `strimage`? Is that an URL? Is that Base64Image data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:SCImageArr[indexPath.row]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.categoriesImages.image = image;
    });
});
```

Also: it has no relation to the question, but don't give variables capitalized names

Comment: does it return nil in data?

Comment: No known class method for selector 'dataFromBase64String:'

Comment: thanks bro image still not showing on collection view

Comment: do you have the data or is it nil? check it

Comment: [
{
type: "0",
image: "https://metro-online.pk/dashboard/images/1617749124.png",
catcode: "221",
level: "2",
brandcode: "0",
brandcampaignpage: "0",
promocode: "0",
weburl: "0",
webtext: "0",
productcode: "0",
text: "Air Conditioning",
browserurl: "0"
},
{
type: "34",
image: "https://metro-online.pk/dashboard/images/1507248489.png",
catcode: "0",
level: "0",
brandcode: "0",
brandcampaignpage: "0",
promocode: "0",
weburl: "0",
webtext: "0",
productcode: "0",
text: "Home Entertainment",
browserurl: "0"
},
]

Comment: this is json but images not coming cell